# Using Object.defineProperty to set array values

Tags: javascript

I am defining an array as a property on an Object using Object.defineProperty.
How do I utilize the usual Array functions in this case ?

Below is the same code:

```
function Foo(){
  this._myArray = null;
}


Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'someArray', {
  get: function(){
    return this._myArray;
  },
  set: function(newValue){
    console.log('set is ' + newValue);
    this._myArray = newValue;
    checkFunction();
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  push: function(newValue){
    console.log('push is ' + newValue);
    this._myArray.push(newValue);
  }

});

function checkFunction(){
 console.log('hello');
}

var test = new Foo();
test.someArray = [1,2];
test.someArray.push(3);
```

As you will notice that the below call does not work:

```
test.someArray.push(3);
```

Plnkr available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HiYPycAN4bloJa44ANWC

Comment: With "does not work" you mean your custom `push` function is not called? That's true. `test.someArray` returns `this._myArray`, so the array's own `push` function is called. `push` is not part of a property descriptor, you cannot magically overwrite the return values methods this way. But since your question is(?) *" How do I utilize the usual Array functions in this case ?"*, it seems the answer is: The same way as with properties that are not getters/setters?

Comment: thanks.. not sure how I would mark your response as an answer